# Django: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have following models:

```py
class Village(models.Model):
    packages_required = models.IntegerField()
    .
    .

class PackageSent(models.Model):
    village = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Village')
    package_count = models.IntegerField()
    sending_user = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Users')
    sending_account_user = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Users')
    .
    .
```

And I need to select all `Villages` along with their `PackageSent` models *not just specific values I can group by*. I built the following query:

```py
ps_query = PackageSent.objects.filter(
                                         filter_logic
                                     ).annotate(
                                         total_account_sent=Sum("package_count"), 
                                         sending_users=ArrayAgg("sender_user_id")
                                     ).distinct(
                                        "sending_account_user_id"
                                     )

Village.objects.filter(
        filter_logic
    ).order_by(
        order_by_logic
    ).annotate(
        packages_missing=F("packages_required") - Sum("packagesent__package_count"),
        users_involved=Count("packagesent__sending_account_user", distinct=True)
    ).prefetch_related(
        models.Prefetch(
            "packagesent_set", 
             queryset=ps_query, to_attr="packages_sent"
        )
    )
```

However the `PackageSent` query raises *annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented error*.

The query I need for `PackageSent` model in MySQL syntax:

```sql
 SELECT 
    *,
    SUM(package_count) AS `total_account_sent`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sending_user) AS `sending_users`
 FROM
    `myapp_packagesent` ps
 LEFT JOIN 
    `myapp_village` v ON v.id = ps.village_id
 GROUP BY 
    `sending_account_user`, 
    `village_id`
 ORDER BY
    `total_account_sent` DESC
```

I would like to do this in a template:

```
{% for village in object_list %}
    .
    .
    .
    {% for package_sent in village.packages_sent %}
        .
        .
        .
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I achieve the results I want?

Technologies used:
Django 3.0 
PostgreSQL

Comment: Hey, can you please fix your code's formatting, it is really hard to read it like this.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan Hope It's a little bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .values, to group by what you want, and then you will not have to use distinct:

```
ps_query = PackageSent.objects.filter(
                                     filter_logic
                                 ).values(
                                     "sending_account_user_id", "village_id"
                                 ).annotate(
                                     total_account_sent=Sum("package_count"), 
                                     sending_users=ArrayAgg("sender_user_id")
                                 )
```

Comment: But I need the whole objects ideally, not just the specific values.

Comment: @popcorn what do you mean by *whole objects ideally*? `group_by` will certainly break this

Comment: @minglyu Or I meant all the fields like you would have in `SELECT *...`, along with some FK relationships.

Comment: @popcorn  something like this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: @minglyu Not really, Also I got an error `Prefetch querysets cannot use values().`

Comment: @popcorn - you can't fetch ungrouped fields - it can give you several values...

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22788347/2881558

Comment: @AK So my only option is to do the `ps_query` separately and then do some for-loops to actually "assign" the packages to villages?

Comment: you can also use values for the vilages data, eg: .values("sending_account_user_id", "village_id", "village__field1", "village__field2").